# MongoDB with node.js trying to make a new file (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wrote a little of code to start learning MongoDB with Node.js in JavaScript but it doesn't work but it doesn't
give a error while running probably someone can help me with that.

The Main code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const test = express();
const Blog = require('./bdSchema');


//connec to mongodb
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://Carsten:<int the real code the password is here>@cluster0.w6iwv.mongodb.net/tomhatesgeschaft?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then((result) => console.log("connected to db"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))



test.get('/add-tomhatesgeschaft', (req, res) => {
    const tomhatesgeschaft = new Blog({
        title: 'hi'
    });
    tomhatesgeschaft.save()
        .then((result) => {
            res.send(result)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
})
```

The BDSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BDSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', BDSchema);
module.exports = Blog;
```

Comment: How are you running this code? Does it log `connected to db` and are you able to request get handler?

Comment: Yes it logs connected to dB Bit what does the second question mean

Comment: Open the browser and run `http:\\localhost:3000/add-tomhatesgeschaft, what does it send?

Comment: When you Namen the Right url than ther is on localhost Website with this url

Comment: Can you give more details of the situation? What do you have now? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

In your Node.js code, change the save function as below.

```
    tomhatesgeschaft.save((err,result) => {
    if (err){
        console.error(err);
    }
    else{
        res.send(result)
    })
})
```

**OR**

```
test.get('/add-tomhatesgeschaft', async (req, res) => {
    const tomhatesgeschaft = new Blog({
        title: 'hi'
    });
    try {
      await tomhatesgeschaft.save()
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
})
```

PS: You should not use `GET` requests for operations such as saving data to the database. Ideally, you should use a `POST` request.

Example with `async`:

```
test.post('/add-tomhatesgeschaft', async (req, res) => {
    const tomhatesgeschaft = new Blog({
        title: 'hi'
    });
    try {
      await tomhatesgeschaft.save()
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: Hört does is it Look when i‘m using post

Comment: Edited my answer. Try following articles like [this](https://bezkoder.com/node-express-mongodb-crud-rest-api/) to get a clear idea on how to develop RESTful APIs

Comment: so i tried all of your solutions but none of them were working